# RESTful windows phone

Tags: wcf, rest

How do I transfer an object in RESTful web service? it seems like RESTful only supports string to exchange data between client and service. thanks

Comment: Are you asking about wp7 or Windows Mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

All web services only support the transfer of a representation of objects. Given the right client, you can easily generate objects with the information passed. For example, using JSON and a javascript client with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), you can easily call `jQuery.parseJSON(stringFromRESTServer);` (or any number of methods in [other good](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) js libraries) to get a js object.

Comment: windows phone does not support DataContractJsonSerializer, does it?

Comment: @user384080, [I think it does](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/bd7d6f01-66b2-496d-a1f2-285489e3177a)

Comment: you cannot use the DataContractJsonSerializer built-in .net framework. However, you can use JSON.NET from codeplex which could serve the same functionality.

Comment: @user384080 - Why can't you use the DataContractJsonSerializer? From MSDN: ["Version Information
 ... Silverlight for Windows Phone:
Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.0, XNA Framework:
Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.0"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(VS.95).aspx) and [" Note:
Partial support for JSON serialization is provided by the DataContractJsonSerializer class."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff637320). Obviously, [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a valid option as well.